# Command works in terminal but do not work in crontab

Tags: command-line, bash, cron

i have a problem with executing terminal simple command in crontab.

**Terminal view:**

```
touch  /home/eugene/`date +%d-%m-%y-%s`.txt
```

**Crontab view:**

```
* *     * * *   root    touch  /home/eugene/`date +%d-%m-%y-%s`.txt
```

If i run this command in terminal, everything works perfect.

Cron log file view (`File: /var/log/cron.log`):

```
Aug 30 22:15:01 eugene-desktop CRON[8809]: (root) CMD (   touch  /home/eugene/`date +)
Aug 30 22:16:01 eugene-desktop CRON[8859]: (root) CMD (   touch  /home/eugene/`date +)
Aug 30 22:17:01 eugene-desktop CRON[8896]: (root) CMD (   touch  /home/eugene/`date +)
```

Comment: I dont write commands directly in crontab. I write them in a shell script and then execute shell script from crontab.

Answer (score 2):

The crontab requires full path of the command. The normal path is not used in crontab.

Try `/bin/touch` or `/usr/bin/touch`, instead of just `touch`

Answer (score 1):

I believe your script should be:

```
* * * * *   root  /usr/bin/touch  /home/eugene/`date +%d-%m-%y-%s`.txt
```

The full path to the `touch` command should be used